# rails db:migrate Failed to open TCP connection connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tcp, migration

I'm getting connection refused whenever I try to migrate on rails. Running `rails db:migrate` gives:

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:8126 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8126)
```

I tried checking if something is already taking up this port using:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8126
```

but there is nothing.

For extra measure, I made sure that docker is not running. Nothing seems to fix the issue though. Not sure what other info to include or what other thing can I try.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: At 1st glance, it has nothing with the migration itself (even if you would set up your DB to use this port and the DB was down the error would be different - more specific, like `PG::ConnectionBad` in case of postgres etc). I guess it's about application initialization in a wider context: Rails runs initializers during the migration phase too, so it looks like something tries to make a connection in question during the app init - the first thing to do is to identify what it is.

Comment: Thanks so much @KonstantinStrukov for the reply. I didnt figure out what it is, but I realized that this is right. The migratyions themselves are ok.